# How to change the css of a dynamically created link button in repeater

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, repeater

I am loading link button in

in a repeater. i want to change the particular link button css class when the user clicks it.

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="moviedaterepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="theatrelinkbutton" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("datetext") %>' CausesValidation="false" CommandName='<%#Eval("datevalue") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("datetext") %>' OnCommand="moviedate_Command"></asp:LinkButton>

            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
```

how to do it i tried with the itemdatabound

```
     protected void moviedaterepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        //Session["linkbuttonid"] = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_moviedaterepeater_ctl01_theatrelinkbutton";
        ////Label lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
        //LinkButton link = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl(Session["linkbuttonid"].ToString());
        //link.CssClass = "active";
    }
}
```

but i want to change the value based on the text of the linkbutton .

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LinkButton theatrelinkbutton = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("theatrelinkbutton");
theatrelinkbutton.CssClass = theatrelinkbutton.Text;
```

You need to add this in `ItemDataBound` event of your repeater control. Please note you should have this event binded:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="moviedaterepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="moviedaterepeater_ItemDataBound">
```

Answer (score 0):

First change your repeater to this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="moviedaterepeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="moviedaterepeater_ItemCommand">
```

Then in code behind:

```
protected void moviedaterepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("theatrelinkbutton");
    lnk.CssClass = "YourCSSClass";
}
```